# Function parameter as this.hint[variableA].variableB

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue.js and would like to

I want to set hint value by variable like this.hint[variableA].variableB = 1

How could I do it

```
data: {
    hint: [{a:0,b:0,c:0},{a:0,b:0,c:0},{a:0,b:0,c:0}],
}

methods: {
  selectHint(){
    this.setHint(0,a) 
  },
  setHint(i,j){
    this.hint[i].j = 1
 },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `hint` is an array of object. To acces one of it's child, you need to access the object at the index `i`.

Then, if you want to add a new variable, if you're doing it like `this.hint[i].newVariable = 1` where `newVariable` isn't already in the object, it won't be reative.

If you want to set reactivity (refresh the dom when this variable is added or change in the future), you can do it by using the `Vue.set()` method (see [this link for more informations](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html))

---

## Example

here when you press the button, il will add a `j` property to the first hint with the value `1`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    hint: [{
      a: 0,
      b: 0,
      c: 0
    }, {
      a: 0,
      b: 0,
      c: 0
    }, {
      a: 0,
      b: 0,
      c: 0
    }],
    selectedHint: 0,
    text: "",
  },

  methods: {
    setHint() {
      Vue.set(this.hint[this.selectedHint], this.text, 1)
      this.text = ""
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <template v-for="(h, index) of hint">
    <p :key="index">{{JSON.stringify(h, null, 4)}}</p>
  </template>
  
  
  <input type="text" label="property" v-model="text" />
  <select v-model="selectedHint" @change="changeSelectedIndex">
    <template v-for="(h, index) of hint">
      <option :key="index" :value="index">{{index}} </option>
    </template>
  </select>
  <button @click="setHint">Add </button>

</div>
```

Comment: thx it works! but how could I get data like Vue.set(this.hint[0], "j")?

Comment: Since it's in a function, you can access every property of your vue component using `this` ! For example, you can have a dropdown and an input where you access your data

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `this.hints[i][j]=1`, but that will [not be reactive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), so you should use `this.$set` helper :

```js
this.$set(this.hints, i ,{ [j] : 1,...this.hints[i]})
```